# How to make update query along with or where condition in mongoDB?

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to update the document with or where condition. (i.e) the condition has to look out on multiple data on the document
Example: Consider the following documents

```
{
 'sender' => '123456',
  'receiver' => '654321',
    'reply_time' => '2 sec'
}
{
 'sender' => '654321',
  'receiver' => '123456',
    'reply_time' => '10 sec'
}
  {
 'sender' => '123456',
  'receiver' => '78945612',
    'reply_time' => '10 sec'
}
```

In this, I want to update 'reply_time' to particular value where the 'sender' is '123456' or 'receiver' is '123456', Is there any way to achieve it by using update query or any any other possible ways ?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following query:

```
db.collection.update(
    {
        $or : [ { "sender" : "123456" }, {"receiver" : "123456"} ]
    },
    { 
        $set: { "reply_time" : <reply_time> }
    }
)
```

If you want to update multiple documents, use **updateMany**.

Hope this helps.